# *ngIf getting reloaded when changing the condition from true to false viceversa in angular-2?

Tags: angular

I am getting an issue with angular-2 while changing the condition to false. initially the div is set to 'true' later when i am changing the condition to false the total page is getting reloaded, output is coming as i expected but facing the reloading issue?

### Here is my code

### In html

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="mymenu.id === expandItem">
     <form class="form-horizontal" #myform="ngForm">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-9 input-group-md form-group">
             <input type="text" ngControl="itemname" [(ngModel)]="items.itemname" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Item Name">
             </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="add(mymenu);">
                        Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

In the component i am changing the expandItem to false.therefor in the *ngif is false the div has to hide.
tried different ways,Relaoding Issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method on the TypeScript side make sure that you return `false` in order to prevent the default browser behavior that you are getting. Another way is to call `event.preventDefault()`, but for that you'll have to pass additional parameter `$event`. However, just calling `return false` should be sufficient.

Have a look at this article on SO [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Husein Roncevic. it works when is returned false.